# How can I destructure this array?

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6

ESLint recommended me to destructure below array to ES6 style(prefer-destructuring). Is it possible to destructure this?

```
params[key] = params[key].split('?')[0];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With array destructuring, you put the left-hand side in `[...]` where each element corresponds to the element you want from the right-hand side. In this case, you just want the first element, so:

```
[params[key]] = params[key].split('?');
```

Live Example:

```js
const params = {
  foo: "foo?bar"
};
const key = "foo";
[params[key]] = params[key].split('?');
console.log(params[key]);
```